# Изменение свойств обьекта

Tags: c#, ооп, объекты

Я хочу изменить свойства обьекта.

```
for (int i = count; i > 0; i--)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ваши запасы еды:");
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, Storage> keyValue in Base.Storages)
    {
        foreach (Food food in keyValue.Value.Foods)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(food.Storage + " " + food.NameOfFood + " " + food.Weight);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Вы хотите накормить животных?");
    string q = Console.ReadLine();
    if (q == "y")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Кого хотите накормить?");
        string v = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, Aviary> keyValue in Base.Aviaries)
        {
            foreach (Animal animal in keyValue.Value.Animals)
            {
                if (animal.Name == v)
                {
                    bool k = animal.Hungry;
                    k = false;
                    HungryAnimal.Remove(animal);
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, Storage> keyvalue in Base.Storages)
                    {
                        foreach (Food food in keyvalue.Value.Foods)
                        {
                            int m = food.Weight;
                            m = food.Weight - animal.FoodForSatiety;
                            Console.WriteLine(m);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

У меня во втором foreach выводится мои запасы еды

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, Storage> keyValue in Base.Storages)
{
    foreach (Food food in keyValue.Value.Foods)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(food.Storage + " " + food.NameOfFood + " " + food.Weight);
    }
}
```

Далее у меня в цикле вот в этом:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, Storage> keyvalue in Base.Storages)
{
    foreach (Food food in keyvalue.Value.Foods)
    {
        int m = food.Weight;
        m = food.Weight - animal.FoodForSatiety;
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
```

m - это значение, сколько осталось еды в складе, и мне это значение надо записать в food.Weight.

Для примера у меня есть животное, которому надо для сытости 5 кг сена. На складе есть 15 кг сена, то есть после кормежки сена должно остаться 10 кг.

То есть мне надо изменить свойство обьекта? Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: `food.Weight -= animal.FoodForSatiety;` и убрать совсем `m`

Comment: кидает ошибку, что food.Weight нельзя использовать в этом контексте потому что метод доступа set нелоступен

Comment: А кто написал метод доступа food.Weight.set ? к тому и претензии..

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что не видя описания вызовов Food, на ваш комментарий не ответить

Comment: по другому сделать это никак нельзя?

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли, спасибо!!